# Cant figure out why my images won't lazyload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys i can't seem to get lazyload to work at all on [my page](http://www.childrenoftheson.com/newindex/Untitled-14.html),  and i can't understand why. I've looked around alot and still have no idea.

I need it as im desinging a new page for my band www.childrenoftheson.com/newindex/Newtest.html and since the whole site is run off one page i need to lazyload images to speed it up.

I would also love to know if anyone could point my in the right direction for lazyloading widgets.

Any help/rage is appreciated :D.

Comment: Is this supposed to be javascript not java?

Comment: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/lazyload

Comment: When I visit the page linked in the question, I get a 404 error on jquery.lazyload.js

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to put java or javascript lol, i have no idea why you get that error and i have gone over http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload so many times but still can't get it work.

Comment: You should fix the javascript errors on [my page](http://www.childrenoftheson.com/newindex/Untitled-14.html) before looking at anything else. How is lazy loading supposed to work if the js file isn't loaded? The file [jquery.lazyload.js](http://www.childrenoftheson.com/newindex/jquery.lazyload.js) does not exist

Comment: I wasn't loading jquery.lazyload.js from inside the newindex folder but i've changed it so that it does now, so that problem should be fixed, but ti still isn't lazyloading.

Answer (score 0):

try pointing lazy load to the correct web path:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

plus loading this way will mean your users might have already downloaded the file and thus saving them time on their page load.

Comment: Sorry forgot to reply earlier, i'm now pointing lazyload to what web path but it still isn't working.

Comment: make sure all assets are pointing to the right url:http://www.childrenoftheson.com/newindex/img/logo.jpg and http://www.childrenoftheson.com/newindex/img/grey.gif" still aren't found by the server.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that the file which contains the jquery plugin (jquery.lazyload.js) cannot be found on your server. It seems to be located  at http://www.childrenoftheson.com/jquery.lazyload.js. In your source code you are including it like this:

```
<script src="jquery.lazyload.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

which resolves the wrong path.

If you are using Firefox, you maybe want to look at the 'Net'-Tab of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see which files cannot be found/loaded...

Comment: i fixed that and using the below answer am now pointing to lazyload using his script link, but it still isn't working, i also updated it on the server so you can see.

Comment: i got it to work after realising that i was resolving the wrong path for the image i was trying to pre-load, thanks for helping me.